# Read File from text file on Android doesn't work

Tags: java, android

Update :: I have changed my code a bit but still bug with lines.get(0) which makes my app crashed again.

```
final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line;
int i = 0;

BufferedReader buffreader = null;
try {
    buffreader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("test.txt")));

    while((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.add(line);
        i++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: And what about your logcat??

Comment: dude what is,  final String lines[]= {};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
final String lines[]= {};
```

creates an array of length 0, so you can't access any elements.

Using a `List<String>` would be a better idea, since you don'T know how many lines you'll read.

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

   // in the loop:
   lines.add( line );
```

Comment: Thank you, I get used to use array[] from other languages.

Comment: I have issue with lines.get(0). How do I do?

Comment: Perhaps you add the code you have now to your Q? If you've added lines correctly it shouldn't occur (if the file isn't empty).

Comment: Did you/can you print the lines as you are adding them to `lines`?

Comment: If the code in your question reads a non-empty file, lines.get(0) cannot "crash". - What is the error message anyway? And how is List `lines` passed on to the app?

Comment: I added this code on my onCreate class. My file isn't empty for sure. I have no idea either. T T

Comment: When I checked i value, it's equal to 0. So I think it's file reader problem but not sure why.

Comment: I have already solve this issue myself thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

use `ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();`

this will allocate memory for you as needed.

Comment: One fine day, that user will read a file with an evil fourth line. - I'd scratch the first proposal.